# KVM does not recognize restart call from guest OS

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am installing Windows XP directly using KVM:

```
kvm -m 256 -hda XP.img -cdrom XP\ DISK\ IMAGE.iso -boot d -smp 1
```

After formatting and initial round of copying files, it remains in the screen saying it's restarting. I have to manually close the QEMU window and start KVM again. How can I get it to respond OS signals?

Comment: I have not an answer, but I would suggest to use `aqemu` GUI interface to qemu/kvm: it is somewhat similar to vbox and rather simple to use.

Comment: How do I use that?

Comment: Simply install and launch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention which version of Ubuntu you are using as the VM host OS.  Providing details about the version numbers of software involved makes it easier to decide on what the answer for a question is.

If you are using Ubuntu 11.04 Natty you might be experiencing a bug which was fixed in later versions.

When the Qemu/KVM process attempts to reboot a bug in KVM causes the clock to jump backwards in time a lot and that causes VM guests to fail to reboot.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/795717 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/882579